# How do I copy int numStudents to Integer i?

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm trying to copy the numStudents int to the i Integer but they always stay the same.
int isn't an object so I've tried to make i an Integer to no avail.
How do I avoid this reference copy?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class passionProject2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer numStudents;


        System.out.println("Enter the amount of students in your class.");

        numStudents = scnr.nextBigInteger();
        String[] studentNames = new String[numStudents];

        System.out.println("Enter your students' full names.");

        Integer i = numStudents;
        while (i >=0) {
            i--;
                studentNames[i] = scnr.nextLine();
                System.out.println(i);
            }


        while (numStudents >=0)
        {
            numStudents--;
            System.out.println(numStudents);
            System.out.println(studentNames[numStudents]);
        }

        }

    }
```

numStudents is too small for the second while to work, it gives an error message that says
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 3
    at passionProject2.main(passionProject2.java:19)

because numStudents is -1

Comment: `while (numStudents >=0) {numStudents--;....}` What happens when `numStudents == 0`?

Comment: A `for` loop seems a more natural choice than a `while` loop here: `for (int i = numStudents - 1; i >= 0; i--) { System.out.println(studentNames[i]); }`. Or, to run through the array the other direction: `for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) { System.out.println(studentNames[i]);}`

Answer (score 1):

At line 16, Integer i = numStudents; value of numStudents is copied to the variable i.
Your java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurs because you need to use ">" instead of ">=" in your while instructions condition; in the last iteration of each while loop, you enter with -1.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class passionProject2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer numStudents;


    System.out.println("Enter the amount of students in your class.");

    numStudents = scnr.nextBigInteger();
    String[] studentNames = new String[numStudents];

    System.out.println("Enter your students' full names.");

    Integer i = numStudents;
    while (i >0) {
        i--;
            studentNames[i] = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println(i);
        }


    while (numStudents >0)
    {
        numStudents--;
        System.out.println(numStudents);
        System.out.println(studentNames[numStudents]);
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Then it only loops twice.

Comment: It loops <numStudents> time. If you have 3 students, it will loop like this:
3>0 -> 3--, studentNames[2] = ...
2>0 -> 2--, studentNames[1] = ...
1>0 -> 1--, studentNames[0] = ...
0>0 -> loop stops

Comment: Integer i = numStudents;  value of numStudents is copied to the variable i. The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occured at lines 19 and 28, where you use the array. Your problem is that you decrement i and numStudents until they reach -1, before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

Everything **should** be int not Integer. Using Integer is your problem as they are full Objects and you are making them equal to each other (i.e. pointing to the same object).

If everything is int they don't refer to each other as the value changes (known as a `primitive` type)

With ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is because you are checking greater then AND equal to (>= instead of just >) so you end up with -1 when you get to last loop

Comment: It should be an `int`, but `==` will happen to work for small numbers (certainly the range involved here).

Comment: When numStudents is an int and i is an int and scnr is taking nextInt, the same exact error occurs. Thats what I originally had them as and tried to change them to Integer to stop this.

Comment: When I try      int i == numStudents; I get an error saying ";" expected after the i, and "not a statement" before the numStudents

Comment: One equals sign not 2. One is for assigning value. Two is for testing equality.

Comment: When I do one equals sign I get the -1 out of bounds error.

Comment: Update your ecample with int and where you are using ==